# I can't cycle my object in my react app, props are undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a whatsapp clone application with react and node. Backend part is ok, I've tested it on postman but I have a problem with my frontend

```
const Chat = ({messages}) => {
    return (
        <div className='chat'>
            <div className='chat_header'>
                <Avatar></Avatar>
                <div className='chat_header_info'>
                    <h3>Chat Name</h3>
                    <p><strong>Last seen: </strong>2 hours ago</p>
                </div>
                <div className='chat_header_right'>
                    <IconButton>
                        <SearchOutlined></SearchOutlined>
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton>
                        <AttachFile></AttachFile>
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton>
                        <MoreVert></MoreVert>
                    </IconButton>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='chat_body'>
                {messages.map((message) =>{
                                    <p className='chat_message'>
                                    <span className='chat_name'>{message.name}</span>
                                    {message.message}
                                    <span className='chat_timestamp'>{message.timestamp}</span>
                                </p>
                })}
                <p className='chat_message chat_receiver'>
                    <span className='chat_name'>Mio nome</span>
                    messaggio
                    <span className='chat_timestamp'>{new Date().toUTCString()}</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div className='chat_footer'>
                <IconButton>
                    <InsertEmoticon></InsertEmoticon>
                </IconButton>
                <form>
                    <input placeholder='Scrivi un messaggio...' type="text"></input>
                    <button type='submit'></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Chat;
```

I do the map of messages object setted in my App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Sidebar from './components/sidebar/Sidebar';
import Chat from './components/chat/chat';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from './axios';
function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/messages/sync").then((response) => {
      setMessages(response.data)
    }).catch();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    var pusher = new Pusher('a2e1d7e0112669256b0c', {
      cluster: 'eu'
    });
    //ogni volta che viene trovato un nuovo messaggio pusher lo accoda alla lista dei messaggi
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('messages');
    channel.bind('insert', function (newMessage) {
      setMessages(...messages, newMessage);
    });
    return () => {
      channel.unbind_all();
      channel.unsubscribe();
    }
  }, [messages]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className='appBody'>
        <Sidebar></Sidebar>
        <Chat messages={messages}></Chat>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm expecting to see the list of messages that I've stored on my db  in the chat body. If I do a console.log of  massage props it result undefined

Comment: What do you get when you console log `response.data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems - first, you are not passing an array to `setMessages`:

```js
setMessages(...messages, newMessage);
```

Should be:

```js
setMessages([...messages, newMessage]);
```

And here:

```js
{messages.map((message) =>{
  <p className='chat_message'>
    <span className='chat_name'>{message.name}</span>
    {message.message}
    <span className='chat_timestamp'>{message.timestamp}</span>
  </p>
})}
```

You have to use round parenthesis and not curly brackets in the map callback, like:

```js
{messages.map((message) => (
  <p className="chat_message">
      <span className="chat_name">{message.name}</span>
      {message.message}
      <span className="chat_timestamp">{message.timestamp}</span>
  </p>
))}
```

This way, you are implicitly returning the `<p>` from the callback.